# No Such Table for Select Query - Android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a LoginActivity.java

```
package com.example.teachify;

/**
 * Created by Sayan on 8/24/13.
 */

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    EditText txtUserName;
    EditText txtPassword;
    Button btnLogin;
    Button btnCancel;
    UserDetails udt;
    private DataBaseManager dataBase;
    String strDetails;

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setting default screen to login.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        //creates and open the database so we can use it
        dataBase = DataBaseManager.instance();

        TextView registerScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_register);
        txtUserName=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
        txtPassword=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);


        // Listening to register new account link
        registerScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Switching to Register screen
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("extra", txtUserName.getText().toString());
                startActivityForResult(i,0);
            }
        });

        btnLogin=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Cursor cursor=null;
                try {
                    cursor = dataBase.select("SELECT UserName,Password FROM User WHERE UserName='" + txtUserName.getText().toString() + "'");
                }
                catch( SQLException e) {
                strDetails="";

                if (cursor == null){
                    cursor.close();
                }
                else {
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    strDetails=cursor.getString(0);
                    cursor.close();
                }

                if((txtUserName.getText().toString()).equals(strDetails)){
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else{
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The DataBaseManager.java

```
package com.example.teachify;

/**
 * Created by Sayan on 9/5/13.
 */
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;


public class DataBaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // The Android's default system path of your application database.
    //data/data/ and /databases remain the same always. The one that must be changed is com.example which represents
    //the MAIN package of your project
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.teachify/databases/";

    //the name of your database
    private static String DB_NAME = "user";

    private static SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;

    private static DataBaseManager sInstance = null;
    // database version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    /**
     * Constructor Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to
     * access to the application assets and resources.
     */
    private DataBaseManager() {
        super(ApplicationContextProvider.getContext(), DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        try {
            createDataBase();
            openDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Singleton for DataBase
     *
     * @return singleton instance
     */
    public static DataBaseManager instance() {

        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new DataBaseManager();
        }
        return sInstance;
    }


    /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
     * database.
     *
     * @throws java.io.IOException io exception
     */
    private void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if (dbExist) {
            // do nothing - database already exist
        } else {

            // By calling this method an empty database will be created into
            // the default system path
            // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
            // database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error(e.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
     * time you open the application.
     *
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase() {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

            // database doesn't exist yet.

        }

        if (checkDB != null) {

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
     * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
     * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
     *
     * @throws java.io.IOException io exception
     */
    public void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = ApplicationContextProvider.getContext().getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    private void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

        // Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    /**
     * Select method
     *
     * @param query select query
     * @return - Cursor with the results
     * @throws android.database.SQLException sql exception
     */
    public Cursor select(String query) throws SQLException {
        return mDataBase.rawQuery(query, null);
    }

    /**
     * Insert method
     *
     * @param table  - name of the table
     * @param values values to insert
     * @throws android.database.SQLException sql exception
     */
    public void insert(String table, ContentValues values) throws SQLException {
        mDataBase.insert(table, null, values);
    }

    /**
     * Delete method
     *
     * @param table - table name
     * @param where WHERE clause, if pass null, all the rows will be deleted
     * @throws android.database.SQLException sql exception
     */
    public void delete(String table, String where) throws SQLException {

        mDataBase.delete(table, where, null);

    }

    /**
     * Update method
     *
     * @param table  - table name
     * @param values - values to update
     * @param where  - WHERE clause, if pass null, all rows will be updated
     */
    public void update(String table, ContentValues values, String where) {

        mDataBase.update(table, values, where, null);

    }

    /**
     * Let you make a raw query
     *
     * @param command - the sql comand you want to run
     */
    public void sqlCommand(String command) {
        mDataBase.execSQL(command);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if (mDataBase != null)
            mDataBase.close();

        super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

}
```

But when I am executing this in the emulator: AVD_for_Nexus_by_Google
I am getting error
No Such Table

I have made a table. Can anyone please help me...

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same problem. I solved it by using below method instead of using getWritableDatabase() to get Databse instance

```
public SQLiteDatabase opendatabase(){
  try{
  String mypath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
  database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
  }catch(SQLiteException sle){
   System.out.println("Exception while opning database : "+sle);
  }
  return database;
 }
```

Because getWritableDatabase() method give empty instance, because its pointing different database location where actually our database not copied from asset folder.

Answer (score 0):

`SQLiteOpenHelper` will automatically create an empty database.
The `checkDataBase` function checks only if the database file exists, but not if it contains the needed tables.

When using `SQLiteOpenHelper`, you are supposed to create the database in the `onCreate` function.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Actually I have updated the onCreate code like this:

Comment: @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User(UserName TEXT,Password TEXT,EMail TEXT)");
    }

Comment: But I am still getting the same error. I am new to this and cannot figure out the problem.

Comment: `onCreate` will not be called twice. Remove your app (and its data) from the device, and reinstall it.

Comment: Actually I am doing this on an emulator (AVD) of Android Studio and not on any real device. So can you please let me know how to remove this from the emulator! I have restarted the application several times.

Comment: The emulated device should have all the normal app management mechanisms (e.g., Settings → Applications → Manage Applications).

Comment: Thanks CL. The thing is resolved. I just removed the emulator and added it again.